# How apply and move a UIImageView layered above another UIImageView Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

i read here many guides how to create a new image merging two existing ones, using the UIGraphics and the layer.render methods for the two UIImageViews, and finally i can create an then save my new image. The problem is that i can't understand how to put the second UIImageView where i want, at the bottom for example. I 'll post now a image of an merged image and the function that my code run making this possible.

[Captured merged photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqNkW.jpg)
[image]

And here's my code that do the trick:

```
extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithWatermark(image1: UIImageView, image2: UIImageView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image1.bounds.size, false, 0.0)

        let frame = image1.frame
        image2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height * 0.80, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height * 0.20 )

        image1.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        image2.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)



        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }
}
```

And then my func that saves the merged image:

```
func addWatermark() {
        let newImage = UIImage.imageWithWatermark(image1: cameraPreview, image2: provaImage)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil,nil,nil)
    }
```

Comment: What's your question? Can you summarize?

Comment: @ethrbunny How to move the second image at the bottom, for example. If you open the image i uploaded, a look at the code, when saved it's at the top, but via code i put it on the bottom, and i see it in my controller on the phone.

Comment: Can you understand now? Or i made the question harder?

Comment: If you can place two UIImageViews as you want in UIView, and take screenshot of UIView, it will give you easy result without much calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function which merge two images and the second will be replaces on bottom

```
func mergeTwoImageSeconInBottom(backgroundImage: UIImage, imageOnBottom: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let size = YOUR_CG_SIZE
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    backgroundImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    imageOnBottom.draw(at: CGPoint(x: (size.width - imageOnBottom.size.width) / 2, y: size.height - imageOnBottom.size.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: Tried to implement it, set the CGSize(width: 100, height :100) for a test, saves and image that is cropped and doesn't show anything but the photo. Tried setting at (width: 1024, height :1024) with an instagram stile, saves a big white square and in the top left corner a little square with the photo inside, and not the other image on top of it at the bottom.

Comment: Also tried switching the order of the two Image.draw calls, as in my code, at the top the second image, as background the first one.